# How to use reserved word as a function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, interpreter

I know there is a [reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words). I just want to use it anyway. Is it related to the interpreter?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: There is no such way to use reserved keywords for user level code. All JS runtime / parser will prevent those.

Comment: Something might break my code. I want to do it anyway... Why?

Comment: If you don't need the name to be specifically a stand-alone function name, assign the function to a property. `var o = {}; o.for = function(){}; o.for();`

Comment: In any programming language, a reserved word or a reserved identifier is a word that cannot be used as an identifier, such as the name of a variable, function, or label. Thus, it is reserved and cannot be used for defining any of these.

Any example or reason you want to do that?

Comment: Well, some website use "debugger" to increase the security of javascript code. Actually, the keyword "debugger" really make the code more difficult to read. 
If there is a way which make "debugger" invalid, things will be fine.

Comment: Short answer is, you can't. Keywords are keywords for a reason. A better question might be, "How do I make the 'debugger' (keyword) make code easier to read?" and then give an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

All function names are actually variables holding a reference to an object of type `Function`. Most often these variables are properties/keys into the global namespace (e.g. `window` in browsers and `global` in Node.js)

So it is entirely possible to write something like this:

```js
global.return = function()
{
  console.log('test');
}

global.return();
```

Of course you can not call it simply by `return()` as this will choke the parser - but `global.return()` or `global.import()` or `global.switch()` is completely achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea to override a reserved function name in any language.
Why not change your function name to have a prefix like 'custom'

```
function customName() {}
```

Comment: Or simply 'my' prefix ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
const functionWithReservedKeywordName = { return () {} }.return
console.log(functionWithReservedKeywordName.name)

// Output: 'return'
```